# Opencv compilation is not working using -lopencv_videoio

Tags: c++, c, opencv, c++11

I have installed opencv2.

`pkg-config --modversion opencv`

> 2.4.13.5

I am using below code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    VideoCapture vid(0);
    if(!vid.isOpened()){
        cout<<"Camera could not load..."<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("webcam",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(1){
        Mat frame;
        bool ctrl = vid.read(frame);
        imshow("webcam",frame);
        if(waitKey(0) == 27){
            cout<<"The app is ended..."<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using, `g++ image_writer.cpp`

> > /tmp/ccPWmgA0.o: In function `main':
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to`cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to`cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to`cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to`cv::waitKey(int)'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to`cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
> >     /tmp/ccPWmgA0.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'
> >     /tmp/ccPWmgA0.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
> >     image_writer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to`cv::Mat::deallocate()'
> >     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

After surfing I found, I have to include lib file

so, I did this. `g++ image_writer.cpp -lopencv_videoio`

> > /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videoio
> >     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know how to fix this. please help me how to fix this. Any hint would be appreciable.

EDIT-1:

`pkg-config --libs opencv` returns,

> -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_ts -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_photo -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lQtCore -lQtTest -lQtGui -lQtOpenGL -lIlmThread -lHalf -lIex -lIlmImf -lImath -ljasper -ltiff -lpng -ljpeg -lswscale-ffmpeg -lavutil-ffmpeg -lavformat-ffmpeg -lavcodec-ffmpeg -lv4l2 -lv4l1 -ldc1394 -lgstpbutils-0.10 -lgstriff-0.10 -lgstapp-0.10 -lgstvideo-0.10 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgstbase-0.10 -lGLU -lGL -lz -latomic -ltbb -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lstdc++

Comment: You can list the linker flags and libraries needed using `pkg-config --libs opencv`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude- please look at the updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenCV "library" is really a collection of multiple libraries, and you usually need to link with multiple libraries.

The simple solution is to use `pkg-config --libs opencv` to get all linker flags and libraries that are needed:

```
g++ image_writer.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: great! it's compiled. could you tell me how to do the same in cmake? i.e., how to add this in Cmakelists.txt file?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Searching for `cmake opencv` turned up [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) as my first hit.

Comment: in my case , your solution didn't work

Comment: @Watson21 Then you're welcome to post a question to ask for help with your problem. You can add a link to my answer to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

compilation using `cmake`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(ImageWriter)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "image_writer.cpp")    
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(" cv_libs:     " ${OpenCV_LIBS})
message(" cv_includes: " ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```